# Override "table tr:nth-child(even/odd) td {}"

Tags: css

Alright, let's try this again.

This is part of the code of my table right now.

```
<table id="infantryTbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="country">Country</th>
            <th class="type">Type</th>
            <th class="nr">Nr</th>
            <th class="name">Name</th>
            <th class="marking">Markings</th>
            <th class="comment">Comment</th>
            <th class="status">Status</th>
            <th class="code">Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="titel" colspan="8">Parachute Company</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="center">British</td>
            <td class="center">Command</td>
            <td class="right">2st</td>
            <td class="left">Rifle/MG</td>
            <td class="left">Company Cmd</td>
            <td class="left">Parachute Company</td>
            <td class="painted">Painted</td>
            <td class="center">BBX16</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With this css I do get every other `<tr>` in a different color.

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) td{
  background:#c1c1c1;color:#1f1f1f;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td{
  background:#b0b0b0;color:#1f1f1f;
}
```

All good so far.

What I want is to change the background and text color on all the cells with the class "painted" and rows with the class "titel".

```
*.titel {background:#424242;}
.painted {background:#375e37;}*
```

As it is now nothing happens when I change the class since the odd/even CSS seems to override everything.

How to I make "titel" and "painted" shown?

Comment: Make your new selector more specific or the existing selectors less specific. What row do you want change, based on what? Attribute, id, class, content...?

Comment: You should probably also post the HTML you have in your question as well.

Comment: Right now it's just a class that id like to use to change a <tr> row  and a <td> cell. [link]http://files.malgol.se/misc/table-override.png

Comment: I'm curious why you started your post with "Alright, let's try this again", given that it's your first post.

Comment: @MrLister Well I rewrote the question trying to make it more clear what the question was. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you used `table tr td` for your odd/even rules, you need the same [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) (or higher) for your override rules, which means you can't use only the class names, like `.painted`, as you see in my last rule. It just doesn't do anything.

```css
table tr:nth-child(odd) td{
  background:#c1c1c1;color:#1f1f1f;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) td{
  background:#b0b0b0;color:#1f1f1f;
}

table tr td.painted {      /* this works */
  background:yellow;
  color:red;
}
table tr td.titel {        /* this works */
  background:red;
  color:black;
}

.painted {                 /* this one doesn't work */
  background:lime;
}
```

```html
<table id="infantryTbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="country">Country</th>
            <th class="type">Type</th>
            <th class="nr">Nr</th>
            <th class="name">Name</th>
            <th class="marking">Markings</th>
            <th class="comment">Comment</th>
            <th class="status">Status</th>
            <th class="code">Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="titel" colspan="8">Parachute Company</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="center">British</td>
            <td class="center">Command</td>
            <td class="right">2st</td>
            <td class="left">Rifle/MG</td>
            <td class="left">Company Cmd</td>
            <td class="left">Parachute Company</td>
            <td class="painted">Painted</td>
            <td class="center">BBX16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="titel" colspan="8">Parachute Company</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="center">British</td>
            <td class="center">Command</td>
            <td class="right">2st</td>
            <td class="left">Rifle/MG</td>
            <td class="left">Company Cmd</td>
            <td class="left">Parachute Company</td>
            <td class="painted">Painted</td>
            <td class="center">BBX16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="titel" colspan="8">Parachute Company</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="center">British</td>
            <td class="center">Command</td>
            <td class="right">2st</td>
            <td class="left">Rifle/MG</td>
            <td class="left">Company Cmd</td>
            <td class="left">Parachute Company</td>
            <td class="painted">Painted</td>
            <td class="center">BBX16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="titel" colspan="8">Parachute Company</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="center">British</td>
            <td class="center">Command</td>
            <td class="right">2st</td>
            <td class="left">Rifle/MG</td>
            <td class="left">Company Cmd</td>
            <td class="left">Parachute Company</td>
            <td class="painted">Painted</td>
            <td class="center">BBX16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="titel" colspan="8">Parachute Company</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="center">British</td>
            <td class="center">Command</td>
            <td class="right">2st</td>
            <td class="left">Rifle/MG</td>
            <td class="left">Company Cmd</td>
            <td class="left">Parachute Company</td>
            <td class="painted">Painted</td>
            <td class="center">BBX16</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not really. I can see that one of the rows that I want in a different color do change but not the rest. Perhaps I should have made myself a tad clearer.  What I want change is cells ith the painted and unpainted class change and then rows with the class=titel.

Comment: @MAlgol Updated my answer, is this how you want?

Comment: @LGSon YES! =) That's it. I did a rewrite of my question, I hope its more clear. Would be bad if my first question on ended on negative.

Comment: Thanks for quick answers. Both David Thomas and LGSon. Should have been more clear in my question. It sounded so good in my head.